# Creating a wicket table with variable rows and columns

Tags: listview, wicket

I'm trying to create a table with a variable number of rows and columns using the wicket framework.
I'm completely novice in the wicket frameWork (from the little I saw this could be achieved using nested ListViews). Can you give me a hid of what the .html and corresponding java code should look like?
In detail, I have a list of engines and each engine has an ID and a variable number of versions. I want to be able to list for each Engine ID the corresponding versions.

The list of engines (An engine is an object) is dynamically created by java code.

Comment: Hi, maybe you can find an answer here: https://examples9x.wicket.apache.org/repeater/

Comment: There are many examples at https://github.com/apache/wicket/tree/master/wicket-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/examples/repeater. You can see them in action in the url @Slawek gave you in an earlier comment.